# Проблема с кнопкой в PyQt5

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, qt-designer, сигналы-слоты

Всем привет, имеется вот такой вот код

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import openpyxl
from random import randint
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMessageBox
import os

question_list = []


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1223, 578)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.QuestionField = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(self.centralwidget)
        self.QuestionField.setObjectName("QuestionField")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.QuestionField)
        self.EntryField = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.EntryField.setObjectName("EntryField")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.EntryField)
        self.ButtonNext = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.ButtonNext.setObjectName("ButtonNext")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.ButtonNext)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

        self.start_quiz()

    def clicked_next(self):
        self.ButtonNext.clicked.connect(self.get_next_question)

    def get_next_question(self):
        self.clicked_next()
        wb_obj = openpyxl.load_workbook("questions.xlsx")
        if len(question_list) < 3:
            wb_sheet = wb_obj['Block_1']
        elif len(question_list) == 3:
            wb_sheet = wb_obj['Block_2']
        elif len(question_list) == 4:
            wb_sheet = wb_obj['Block_3']
        else:
            sys.exit(app.exec_())

        rows = wb_sheet.max_row
        nums_wb = randint(2, rows)
        question = wb_sheet[f'A{nums_wb}'].value
        print(question)
        print(len(question_list))
        self.QuestionField.setText(question)
        question_list.append(question)

    def start_quiz(self):
        greetings = QMessageBox()
        btn_begin = QtWidgets.QPushButton()
        greetings.setWindowTitle('Приветствие')
        greetings.setText(
            f'Приветствую тебя {os.getlogin()}. Предлогаю в начале рабочего дня пройти тебе тест на знание наших цен и предложений')
        greetings.setIcon(QMessageBox.Information)
        greetings.exec_()
        self.get_next_question()

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Опросник"))
        self.ButtonNext.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Далее"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

При нажатии на кнопку **`далее`**, почему-то он **`дважды`** выдает значение, а не один раз. 
Смысл такой, что в начале воспроизводиться приветственное сообщение из функции `start_quiz`, далее начинается опрос функция `get_next_question` и после того как пользователь ввел свой ответ и нажимает на кнопку `clicked_next` должна вызваться снова функция `get_next_question` и так пока длина списка не будет больше **`4`**.

Но когда я нажимаю на кнопку **`далее`**, то функция смены вопроса начинает выдавать по **`2`** значения сразу. 
Не знаю куда смотреть

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы не предоставили воспроизводимый пример. Без файла **questions.xlsx** проверить ваше приложение нет возможности.

Некоторые рекомендации для вас:

- **НИКОГДА НЕ ИЗМЕНЯЙТЕ код, сгенерированный Qt Designer, НИКОГДА.** 
  Создайте другой класс, который наследуется от соответствующего виджета, и используйте созданный класс для его заполнения.
- строка `self.ButtonNext.clicked.connect(self.get_next_question)` находится не в том месте, как и строка `self.wb_obj = openpyxl.load_workbook("questions.xlsx")`
- ну и наконец, некоторое виртуальные мысли по поводу вашего кода, для вашей проверки см. ниже.

---

```
import os
import openpyxl
from random import randint
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMessageBox


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1223, 578)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.QuestionField = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(self.centralwidget)
        self.QuestionField.setObjectName("QuestionField")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.QuestionField)
        self.EntryField = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.EntryField.setObjectName("EntryField")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.EntryField)
        self.ButtonNext = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.ButtonNext.setObjectName("ButtonNext")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.ButtonNext)
        
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Опросник"))
        self.ButtonNext.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Далее"))


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        
        self.question_list = []                                           # +++
        self.wb_obj = openpyxl.load_workbook("questions.xlsx")            # +++
        
        self.ButtonNext.clicked.connect(self.get_next_question)           # !!! +++
        
        self.start_quiz()
        self.get_next_question() 

#    def clicked_next(self):
#        self.ButtonNext.clicked.connect(self.get_next_question)

    def get_next_question(self):
#        self.clicked_next()
#        wb_obj = openpyxl.load_workbook("questions.xlsx")
        
        if len(self.question_list) < 3:
            wb_sheet = self.wb_obj['Block_1']
        elif len(self.question_list) == 3:
            wb_sheet = self.wb_obj['Block_2']
        elif len(self.question_list) == 4:
            wb_sheet = self.wb_obj['Block_3']
        else:
#            sys.exit(app.exec_())
            self.close()

        rows = wb_sheet.max_row
        nums_wb = randint(2, rows)
        question = wb_sheet[f'A{nums_wb}'].value
        print(question)
        print(len(self.question_list))
        self.QuestionField.setText(question)
        self.question_list.append(question)

    def start_quiz(self):
        greetings = QMessageBox()
        btn_begin = QtWidgets.QPushButton()
        greetings.setWindowTitle('Приветствие')
        greetings.setText(
            f'Приветствую тебя {os.getlogin()}. Предлогаю в начале рабочего дня пройти тебе тест на знание наших цен и предложений')
        greetings.setIcon(QMessageBox.Information)
        greetings.exec_()
        
#        self.get_next_question()        


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: спасибо за указание недостатка, понял, на будущее запомню, и спасибо за правки,
https://dropmefiles.com/rQFQA вот ссылка на скачивание файла

Comment: подскажи еще пожалуйста, то есть в основном коде сгенерированным  **Qt Designer ** даже не желательно поменять размер окна?

Comment: Ruin пожалуйста, но я не понял, код, который я написал не работает? Я не вижу, файла по указанной ссылке.

Comment: Код рабочий спасибо, [https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WKymcPzKrgxBLLMYD5s5TTW9S3t5Drfn/edit?usp=share_link&ouid=109137112156684725929&rtpof=true&sd=true] вот ссылка на файл

Comment: И подскажи если не сложно, как реализовать правильно запись в файл csv в формате вопрос ответ?
дописал вот такую функцию `def write_to_file(self, question, answer):
        with open(f"{os.getlogin()}_{datetime.date.today()}.csv", 'a',
                  encoding='cp1251', errors='replace', newline='') as file:
            writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter=';')
            writer.writerow([question, answer])`
вызываю эту функцию из функции `def get_next_question(self)` но запись происходит очень странно

Comment: @Ruin пожалуйста, если у вас есть другие проблемы - задайте новый вопрос.